# Channel lastModifiedDateTime ist simply wrong

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Everytime I update the channels drive by uploading a file, the lastModifiedDateTime gets updated, it's not correct though.

[Channel Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZpYb.png)

You can see that at the time I make this post, its 2020-10-08T11:04Z

Anyone got any info on this?

Comment: Are you sure these are related? I'd be surprised if uploading a file to the channel's drive (which is in the end just uploading to SharePoint, not Teams per se), actually modifies the 'last updated' of the channel itself.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow the attribute definitely got updated after uploading a file in a channel. I read in another thread that when uploading a file directly with GraphAPI Post the attribute gets set correctly

Comment: ok thanks,g ood to know